# Why am I receiving a nil value in this imageview?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to display an image in a scrollview, but I am receiving a nil error upon execution.

```
    var imageView: UIImageView!
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "image")!
```

Comment: what is exactly the error ?

Comment: Which line did the error fall on?

Comment: If you are asking "why is `imageView` nil?" it is because you have never initialised it

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to instantiate imageView before setting the frame.

e.g.

```
self.imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "image"))
```